# DBeaver: Use Windows authentication from linux to connect SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows, dbeaver, mssql-jdbc

I am using

- Debian GNU/Linux 11
- dbeaver Community Edition 22.3.0

to try to connect to `Microsoft SQL Server 2017`.

[image]

and I always get this error:

```
This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:f159b733-7a07-4c03-983e-803e9fbd7a33
  no mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
  no mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
```

When I check driver configuration I see `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc_auth` and `mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64.dll` is missing.

[image]

[image]

```
$ ls ~/.local/share/DBeaverData/drivers/maven/maven-central/com.microsoft.sqlserver/
mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8.jar
mssql-jdbc-9.2.0.jre8.pom
mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64.pom
```

Should I have `mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.0.x64.dll`? Can a dll work in Linux? Is there any workaround to simulate Windows authentication from Linux?

Answer (score 0):

On Dbeaver select **NTLM authentication** add your user and password, then go to **Driver properties** tab and add your **domain**.